# Index of the first element of array matching a boolean condition

Tags: javascript

I need to find an index of the first element matching the condition in an array. The array elements are dates in string format. My code works but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do that:

```
const dateIndex = dates.indexOf(dates.find( e => new Date(e) > new Date(dataDate)));
```

where `dates` is my array.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex?

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks. Sometimes it is quite hard to dig through that documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already an efficient way but if you want to improve it more the best you can do is:

```js
const dateIndex = dates.findIndex(e => new Date(e) > new Date(dataDate));
```